# when changing the font size the text is misaligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text ("Bokdeko") that with a size of 20px is fine, but if I modify the font size to 30px it gets misaligned as you can see in the images:
with 20px: https://postimg.cc/75bSFGnR
with 30px: https://postimg.cc/0M1mKt1g
As you can see, the text "Bokdeko" appears scrolled down in the second image, which is the one with a font size of 30px.
this is the css and html code that I have.
the css file:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oranienbaum&family=PT+Sans+Narrow&display=swap);
 
.icono
{
width:30px;
height:20px;
}

.nav-section .row {
height: 30px;
align-items: center;
}
 
.contenedor{

width:485px;
height:540px;/*tamaño alto foto*/
    margin :auto;
}
 
 .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { 
    color:black !important;
}

.titulo{
  font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;  
   font-size: 30px; 
}
```

the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/bootstrap.css" TYPE="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
        <style>
            .icono
                        {
                            width:30px;/*tama�o del icono*/
                            height:20px;
                        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row nav-section" >
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2 bg-secondary my-auto" style="z-index:3;">
    <!--<div class="hamburguer">-->
<div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">
<div class="col-4">   
        <div>
                                <ul class="nav">
                                        <li><img class="icono"  src="hamburguer.png">
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="">Tienda</a>
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li><a href="">Ver todo</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Armarios</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sillas</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sillones</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Sofás</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Mesas</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Mesillas y cajoneras</a></li>
                                                                        <li><a href="">Lámparas</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="blog_principal.php">Blog</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="minimalista.php">Estilo minimalista</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="nordico.php">Estilo nórdico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="retro.php">Estilo retro</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="rustico.php">Estilo rústico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="clasico.php">Estilo clásico</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="exteriores.php">Espacios exteriores</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="fusion_estilos.php">Fusión de estilos</a></li>                     
                                                        <!--</li>-->
                                                </ul>
                                        </li>
                                                </ul>
                                        </li>   
                                </ul>

                        </div>              

    </div> <!-- div col-->
            <div class="col-8 titulo bg-info">
            <a href="#">BOKDEKÓ</a>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-5 bg-danger my-auto" >
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">

            <div class="col-2">    
            <a href ="#">Cuenta</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
            <a href ="#">Registrarse</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">    
            Busca productos
            <input type=text name=buscar size='12' maxlength='15' value='' style="padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--div col-->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-5 bg-info my-auto"><!--align-self-center-->
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px !important;margin-bottom:30px !important;">
                <div class="col-3 ">
                <a href="#">Mi lista</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 bg-success">
                <a href ="#">Carrito</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 bg-warning">
                <a href="#">Hola</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--div col-->
    </div> <!--div row-->
</div>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/utilidades.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear for us before you can produce a minimal example out of your code. The current code outputs no styling. You can use external editor like Codesandbox for easing the process.

Comment: i have edited it separating styles and html

Comment: You mention the text “Bokdeko” appears scroll down In the second image. With your current code is unable to replicate the issue. You might provide more information such as the “estilos_menu.css”, or use external editor as @m4n0 mention before. (Codepen, jsfiddle etc. are good alternative)

Comment: if you change the .titulo style to :.titulo{
  font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;  
   font-size: 30px; 
} you can see the "bokdeko" misaligned

Comment: it's edited, now you can see the issue.

Comment: Add the .d-flex and .align-items-center classes to your three .col's.  I assume that you are learning about bootstrap which is why there are a lot of non-bootstrap style definitions and the overuse of !important. You can achieve the desired look without these by just using the classes and structures that bootstrap provides.  See if you can refactor those out of there.

Comment: ok, works fine. I used d-inline instead of flex for displaying the label and the textbox in the same line, thanks!